# Как организовать структуру очистки кэша по ключу в Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, архитектура, кэширование, структуры, laravel5

При выводе товаров, данные кэшируются.
Как сбросить кэш по ключу при сохранении или удалении данных **в нескольких связанных моделях** (товар, категория, и т.д.)?

Не хотелось бы дублировать код для каждого события, да еще и в разных моделей, например:

```
public function saved()
{
    if (Cache::has('my_cache_key')) {
        Cache::delete('my_cache_key');
    }
}

public function deleted()
{
    if (Cache::has('my_cache_key')) {
        Cache::delete('my_cache_key');
    }
}
```

Может быть как то передать ключ в какой то класс / метод, наследоваться... ?

Comment: В чем проблема использовать трейт?

Comment: Вероятно непонимание этого.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

как уже писали, сделай трэйт

```
trait Cache
{
    public function saveCache(string $key, $value)
    {
        if (!Cache::has(key)) {
            Cache::put($key, $value);
        }
    }

    public function deleteCache(string $key)
    {
        if (Cache::has($key)) {
            Cache::delete($key);
        }
    }
}
```

Добавь в модель

```
class Product extends Eloquent
{
   use Cache;
}
```

Используй так

```
$product = new Product();
$product->deleteCache('cache_key');
```

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, где вы храните трейты в своих проектах?

Comment: @MixJay app/Models/Traits

Answer (score 0):

По совету выше, дял себя сделал так:

В моделях товаров и категорий прописал

```
use DeleteCacheDiscountsTrait;
```

Сам трейт выглядит так:

```
trait DeleteCacheDiscountsTrait
{
    use CacheTrait;

    private $key = 'discounts_cache_key';

    public static function bootDeleteCacheDiscountsTrait()
    {
        static::saving(function ($item) {
            $item->deleteCache($item->key);
        });

        static::deleting(function ($item) {
            $item->deleteCache($item->key);
        });
    }
}
```

События начинают подхватываться автоматом средствами Laravel, главное чтобы приставка была boot + имя трейта.

В добавок, сам трейт использует трейт кэша:

```
trait CacheTrait
{
    public function deleteCache(string $key)
    {
        if (Cache::has($key)) {
            Cache::delete($key);
        }
    }
}
```

Не знаю, на сколько намудрено, но работает. Пока так и оставил, а Observer отключил.